# how to get specific item sold history through eBay Api

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I am using the eBay shopping API and I cannot find a way to get the specific item sale history fields. I tried Google but found nothing.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What kind of data are you hoping to get back exactly?

Comment: i need sold history for specify items fields like userId,price,quantity,date of purchase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [GetItemTransactions()](http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetItemTransactions.html) in the Trading API that might suit your needs.